# How to get a button's id when being clicked in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, button

I have checked some of the similar questions which were asked.

I want to add/delete buttons when users click the add/delete buttons dynamically. Therefore, each button has to have a unique id to identify themselves.

Here is part of the html code:

```
<p id="q1">Question: 1<input type="text" class="ttt"/>
<button class="buttonPlus" type="button"></button>
<button class="buttonMinus" type="button" id="1"></button></p>
```

Here is part of the jQuery code:

```
var questionCount = 1;
$("#q1").append("<p id='p2'>Question: " + ++questionCount + "<input type='text'>\
<button type='button' class='buttonPlus'></button>\
<button type='button' class='buttonMinus' id=questionCount></button></p>");
//Re-binding
var newBtnPlus = $("#q1").find('.buttonPlus:last');
var newBtnMinus = $("#q1").find('.buttonMinus:last');
newBtnPlus.click(function(){
    btnPlsClickEvent(newBtnPlus);
});
newBtnMinus.click(function () {
    btnMnsClickEvent(newBtnMinus);
});



function btnMnsClickEvent(btn) {
var idNum = $(this).attr("id");
alert(idNum);}
```

Besides the method above, I have tried:
alter(this.id);
alter(btn.id);
.etc.

I don't know why I can't get the id I have dynamically assigned to the minus buttons, nor can I get the statically assigned one which is done by the html.

I have been stuck by this question for hours. 
Could you help me?

Thanks,
Ashley

Comment: I assume you're binding the minus/plus event to multiple elements, thus the reason to break off in to separate "btnMnsClickEven" functions?

Comment: What are you expecting to be returned? A couple of notes: it's symantically illegal to use an id that starts with a number. Also, the id you're setting when you're creating the elements via javascript is missing quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply pass a reference to the button when you go to call the generic function:

```
newBtnMinus.click(function () {
  btnMnsClickEvent(this); // use "this" instead of your selector object
});

function btnMnsClickEvent(btn) {
  var idNum = btn.id; // now reference the button you pass
  alert(idNum);
}
```

Comment: @AlienWebguy: lol, thanks. Though reputation is just the added-bonus to helping. ;-)

Comment: I disagree - the rep unlocks privileges which allow us to contribute better. At 20k you're a trusted user, my friend :) http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user

Comment: @AlienWebguy: I was merely mentioning that I do it because I want to, not because I battle for rep. I've seen enough people come on here and do everything they can to get to 100k in as short of a time as possible, albeit for bragging rights, because they feel the need to, etc. Though I do my best to help out, it's more important to me to provide helpful answers (just as I command the same from others when I ask questions); not the proverbial "battle to be the first [up-voted] answer".

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `$(this).attr('id')` when you can simply use `this.id`

```
$('button').click(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```